# Sass Conventions

Tags: css, sass

This is a question about sass best practices.

Lets say I have a _colors.scss file that contains variable assignments like:

```
 $white : #ffffff;
 $black : #000000;
```

And i have a _typography.scss file that uses the color variables:

```
 H1 {
 color: $white;
 }
 h2 {
  color : $black;
  }
```

In the styles.scss file:

I import as such:
@import "colors";
@import "typography";

My thoughts are that in the screen.scss file you would import colors first then typography. The variables are available to both typography and screen because colors was imported first.

Someone told me that you must import _colors.scss in both _typography.scss and styles.scss. Wouldn't that be redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago I had some issues with Rails' asset pipeline whereby I had to import the mixin/variable stylesheet in every other stylesheet for it to precompile properly on Heroku. I have no idea if this issue still exists or not, or if it was just a problem with my configuration, but if you can import the file just once in a main stylesheet, and it works in development, and it compiles, then I think it's safe to say you *don't* have to include it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your thinking.  Once you import your variables, they will be available to other @imports as long as it is done before a variable is called.

You should take a look at "[How to structure a sass project](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project)".  Its pretty helpful

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to import it twice.

I recommend using a project_variable.scss file where you declare all your variables you gonna use in your project. An import it at the begin of your main.css (where you import _colors et _typo).